# Windows 10 ugrade

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I want to upgrade to windows 10 64-bit from windows 7 64-bit, but I saw on the Windows 10 that I require *3:CMPXCHG16b*, *PrefetchW*, and *LAHF/SAHF*. So I want to know if I have this, and can I upgrade my PC?

My PC:

- Intel Core i3-2100 CPU 3.10 GHz
- 4 GB RAM

Comment: The best way to know if you can run Windows 10 is attempt the upgrade, if your hardware is not supported, you will be told it isn't supported at that point in time.

Comment: how can I recheck my system with the get windows app ? it checked my system on 09.26 but I installed a few more programs

Comment: Sounds like your hardware is compatible.  You don't need to check your system again.  Any incompatible software simply won't be transferred and will exist in the Windows.old directory when the upgrade is finished.

Answer (score -1):

They are CPU features. For understanding, your CPU has these flags (futures). In cmd, run coreinfo or use the cpuz utiliy (it's free).

Comment: it didn't help it can't find those information